# легка куртка: вітрОвка чи вітрІвка?

Tags: вибір-слова, іменники, морфологія

В інтернеті зустрічаються обидва варіанти:

- *вітровка* ([Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECWCS), [крамниця1](https://www.svitstyle.com.ua/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96))
- *вітрівка* ([крамниця2](http://ovactive.com/shop/woman/zhinocha-vitrivka-columbia-splash))

Чи є якесь правило словотворення, на яке можна орієнтуватись при виборі назви цього типу одягу?

Comment: Вітрівка є правильним варіантом вживання через закритий склад (о вживається у відкритих складах)

Comment: То є так, але є винятки, наприклад _кінець_ супроти _конець_. Було б непогано ще чимось підґрунтити.

Comment: @stegetsj а хіба кінець розбивається на склади як кін-ець?

Comment: @P.Vowk Нї, бо за такою лоґікою було би _кіт-и_, а не _ко-ти_. Ну або _кош-еня_ проти умовного _кіш-ка_.

Comment: Чому б не "штормівка"?

Answer (score 5):

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=140308&page=485) має слово **вітрівка** — *легка куртка із цупкої тканини, що захищає від вітру*. Також в [російсько-українському словнику](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) пропонують слово **вітрівка**. Але на противагу, в [ВТССУМ](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/25317/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) знайша **вітровку**, а також безліч інтернет-магазинів використовують це слово. На жаль ніякого правила щодо утворення цього слова не знайшла. Проте, на мою думку, якщо оновлений тлумачний словник пропонує **вітрівку**, то краще вживати це слово.